# Wireframe plotting using 2 different color

Tags: r, plot

I'm using the `wireframe` function in order to obtain a 3d plot. Since I'm using some models in order to forecast, I want to plot observed and forecasted values in the sime wireframe plot, but I want to know if it's possible to change color from the begin of forecasting. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHjxe.png) is the result I obtain using this code:

```
wireframe(grid$mxt~grid$ages*grid$years,
      xlab=TeX("$x$"),ylab=TeX("$t$"),zlab=TeX("$log\\mu_x(t)"),
      drape = TRUE,col="black",
      col.regions = colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "red"))(100),
      scales = list(arrows=FALSE, cex=0.8, col = "black", font = 1),
      aspect=c(1,0.6))
```

What I want is to change the surface color from the 2011 years, in order to make understandable the plot. I attach the [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kzldtop4z4uru9d/data.txt?dl=0). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I partially solved. It seems that wireframe function does not plot different surface with different (x,y). So what you have to do is to extend the data, in order to have two different surface that have the same (x,y), but before a certain y one of them contains NA, and after the other one contains NA. I post the code I used and the results (well I have to change colours but thi is quite easy).

This is an age-year plot, with z equal to log-mortality rate for ages and years. The matrix `mxt1` is of dimension (n, n1), while the matrix pred is of dimension (n, n2); y1 is a vector of dimension n1 (years of observed values) while y2 is of dimension n2 (years of predicted values).

```
grid<-expand.grid(list(ages=ages, years=c(y1,y2)))
grid<-rbind(grid,grid)
grid$mxt <- c(cbind(mxt1, matrix(nrow=n,ncol=n2)),
          cbind(matrix(nrow=n,ncol=(n1-1)),mxt1[,n1],pred))
grid$group <- factor(c(rep("obs",n*n1+n*n2),rep("for",n*n1+n*n2)))

wireframe(mxt~ages*years,data=grid,
      groups=group, col.groups=c("red","green"))
```

The trick in the second part of vector grid$mxt is for bind the two surface. The result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWCNB.png).

Hope to have helped someone.